# Finding rows by their difference in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a data frame in which I want to identify all pairs of rows whose time value `t` differs by a fixed amount, say `diff`.

```
In [8]: df.t
Out[8]:
0    143.082739
1    316.285739
2    344.315561
3    272.258814
4    137.052583
5    258.279331
6    114.069608
7    159.294883
8    150.112371
9    181.537183
...
```

For example, if `diff = 22.2423`, then we would have a match between rows 4 and 7.

The obvious way to find all such matches is to iterate over each row and apply a filter to the data frame:

```
for t in df.t:
    matches = df[abs(df.t - (t + diff)) < EPS]
    # log matches
```

But as I have a log of values (10000+), this will be quite slow.

**Further**, I want to look and check to see if any differences of a multiple of `diff` exist.  So, for instance, rows 4 and 9 differ by `2 * diff` in my example.  So my code takes a long time.

Does anyone have any suggestions on a more efficient technique for this?

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit: Thinking about it some more, the question boils down to finding an efficient way to find floating-point numbers contained in two lists/Series objects, to within some tolerance.

If I can do this, then I can simply compare `df.t`, `df.t - diff`, `df.t - 2 * diff`, etc.

Comment: Sort the values first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check *many* multiples, it might be best to take the modulo of `df` with respect to `diff` and compare the result to zero, within your tolerance.

Whether you use modulo or not, the efficient way to compare floats within some tolerance is [numpy.allclose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html). In versions before 1.8, call it as `numpy.testing.allcose`.

So far what I've described still involved looping over rows, because you must compare each row to every other. A better, but slightly more involved approach, would use [scipy.cKDTree](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html) to query all pairs within a given distance (tolerance).